# Непонятное поведение переменной в цикле for

Tags: c++, циклы, c++11, c++14, for

Подскажите, с чем связано такое поведение:

```
int count = 0;

for (auto& data : array)
{
    std::cout << (count++) << std::endl;
}
```

выводится одно и тоже число (0)

лечится, если объявить статическую переменную

```
static int count = 0;
```

С чем это связано? И как с этим бороться?\

Более точный код:

```
// проанализировать данные
void
analyzeData
(
    const std::string&  pathIn,
    blocks_t&           blocks,
    const std::string&  pathOut = ""
)
{
    CScience_Fit fitManager;

    static int blocksCount = 0; // только со static начало работать

    for (auto& block : blocks)
    {
        std::cout << "[" << (blocksCount++) << "]\t" << block.m_path << std::endl; // вот тут должно было происходить изменение переменной blocksCount, но не происходило

        for (auto& data : block.m_data)
        {
            // аппроксимировать данные
            CScience_Points points;
            points.initialize(data.second.m_raw);

            constexpr int minCurvesAmount = 1;
            constexpr int maxCurvesAmount = 10;

            for (int curvesAmount = minCurvesAmount; curvesAmount <= maxCurvesAmount; curvesAmount++)
            {                    
                data.second.m_fit.push_back(fitManager.alg_v2(points, i_limits_t(1, points.m_pointAmount), curvesAmount, nullptr));
            }

            // сформировать имя файла
            std::string pathFull = "";

            if (pathOut.size() == 0)
            {
                pathFull = pathIn + "\\" + block.m_info + "[" + std::to_string(data.first) + "].csv";
                std::replace(pathFull.begin() + 3, pathFull.end(), ':', ' ');
            }
            else
            {
                pathFull = pathIn + "\\" + pathOut;
            }

            // сохранить данные
            data.second.save(pathFull);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну если array имеет размер 1, то выводиться будет только 0. Как и должно быть. Зачем с этим "бороться"? Где остальной код, кстати? Что такое array? По вашему описанию видно, что вы скрыли критически важные куски.

Comment: @Ant, в том то и дело, что `array` имеет большой размер, но изменение переменной не происходит

`array` - это вектор структур,
сейчас в своем вопрос добавлю код

Comment: Ваше "добавление кода" ничего не дало. Что такое `blocks_t`? Если это вектор, то значит ваш вектор имеет размер 1.

Comment: В отладчике что видно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исходя из того кода который вы опубликовали в вопросе, логично предположить что вектор/массив `blocks` имеет размер равен одному элементу при каждом вызове функции `analyzeData`.
А ключевое слово `static` заставляет сохранять значение переменной `blocksCount` внутри области видимости функции `analyzeData` до того момента пока приложение не будет завершено.

То есть по сути, с помощью статической переменной вы сохраняете состояние переменной `blocksCount` от вызова к вызову функции `analyzeData`.

Я бы посоветовал вам в режиме дебага проследить за переменной `analyzeData` и отследить её значение при каждом вызове функции `analyzeData`. Вероятно что в некоторых случаях эта переменная содержит внутри всего один элемент.

Если вы опубликуете больше кода с логикой приложения - можно будет дать более точный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Ребята, я дико извиняюсь, я действительно тупарь и вектор действительно имеет размер 1, просто я функцию вызываю (с разными данными/векторами) несколько раз :)

А в голове сидело, что у меня несколько блоков (так действительно происходит, но в других случаях).

Просто глаза замылились

Comment: Бывает) Для этого и есть stackoverflow - свежий взгляд со стороны.